# Developing an app as a website for portability to ios and Android

Tags: html, ios, offline

I was thinking of writing a simple android app that would just contain my notes I've made for my job for my own personal reference. I figuered perhaps some of my co-workers would want to use this app too, but most of them use IPhones. I don't own any Apple products and I know nothing about developing for iOS. After some research I've decided perhaps the best approach is to develope the 'app' as a website instead, to be viewed offline. Does this approach make sense, and could I distribute such a product on an Apple device without any issues?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend developing an offline application with [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). PhoneGap allows you to build your app once with web--standards, wrap it with PhoneGap, and then deploy it to multiple mobile platforms.